# API.ai Intent Score in JSON

Tags: nlp, dialogflow-es

Does API.ai provide the actual intent score, and not simply a binary 1 or 0, in a JSON response?  Thanks for the guidance (and hopefully not a stupid question).

Answer (score 1):

In short- Yes. After getting the response from apiAiService, the intent score can be accessed via:

response.result.score

In general- A full preview of the actual JSON response to any request you send the API is available right on hand side of the console page of API.ai itself.

https://console.api.ai/api-client

Go to 'try it now' and after sending any query click SHOW JSON.